# WCF call nested in a WCF call

Tags: ios, objective-c, wcf, uitableview, wsdl2objc

I have a backend made in C#, where I am making WCF calls to from iOS. It works pretty good, but I am stuck in a problem
Code:

```
#import "ListTableViewController.h"
#import "ListServiceSvc.h"
#import "LoginViewController.h"

@interface ListTableViewController (){
    NSMutableArray *productsFromWebServer;
    NSMutableDictionary *prodForList;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *shoppingList;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *productList;

@end

@implementation ListTableViewController

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    NSUserDefaults *standardUserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    Boolean b = [standardUserDefaults boolForKey:@"HasTokenKey"];
    if (!b)
    {
        [self showLoginViewController];
    }
    [self loadListsFromRemoteServer];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
    //self.uname.text = [standardUserDefaults objectForKey:@"username"];
}

- (void) showLoginViewController {
    LoginViewController* loginController = (LoginViewController*) [ApplicationDelegate.storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LoginViewController"];
    [self presentViewController:loginController animated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void)userDidLeave
{
    NSUserDefaults *standardUserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [standardUserDefaults setBool:NO forKey:@"HasTokenKey"];

    // Show the Login screen. 
    [self showLoginViewController];
}

- (IBAction)exitAction
{
    [self userDidLeave];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    _shoppingList = [NSMutableArray array];
    _productList = [NSMutableArray array];
    //[self loadListsFromRemoteServer];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

-(void) loadListsFromRemoteServer
{
    NSString *uname = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"username"];
    NemListBinding *binding  = [[ListServiceSvc NemListBinding]initWithAddress:@"http://balder/dm76_gr5/WCF.ListService.svc/custom?singleWsdl"];
    binding.logXMLInOut=YES;
    ListServiceSvc_GetShoppingListsWithUname *parms = [[ListServiceSvc_GetShoppingListsWithUname alloc]init];
    parms.uname = uname;
    [binding GetShoppingListsWithUnameAsyncUsingParameters:parms delegate:self];
}

-(void) loadItemsInList:(NSNumber*)slistId
{
    NemListBinding *binding  = [[ListServiceSvc NemListBinding]initWithAddress:@"http://balder/dm76_gr5/WCF.ListService.svc/custom?singleWsdl"];
    binding.logXMLInOut=YES;
    ListServiceSvc_GetProductsWithListId *parms = [[ListServiceSvc_GetProductsWithListId alloc]init];
    parms.listId = slistId;
    [binding GetProductsWithListIdAsyncUsingParameters:parms delegate:self];
}

- (void) operation:(NemListBindingOperation *)operation completedWithResponse:(NemListBindingResponse *)response
{
    NSArray *responseHeaders = response.headers;
    NSArray *responseBodyParts = response.bodyParts;
    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1.0];
    NSMutableArray *shoppingListFromWebserver = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    productsFromWebServer = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    prodForList = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    // step 1 fill in the blanks.
    for(id header in responseHeaders) {
        // here do what you want with the headers, if there's anything of value in them
    }
    for (id mine in responseBodyParts)
    {
        if ([mine isKindOfClass:[ListServiceSvc_GetShoppingListsWithUnameResponse class]])
        {
            for (id slist in [[mine GetShoppingListsWithUnameResult] ShoppingList])
            {
                [shoppingListFromWebserver addObject:slist];
                [self loadItemsInList:[slist ShoppingListId]];
//NSLog(@"new list :: RESPONSE FROM SERVER :: nList %@", [slist ShoppingListName]);
            }
        }
        if ([mine isKindOfClass:[ListServiceSvc_GetProductsWithListIdResponse class]])
        {
            for (id products in [[mine GetProductsWithListIdResult] Product])
            {
                [prodForList setObject:[products ProductName] forKey:[products ShoppingListId]];
                NSLog(@"new product :: RESPONSE FROM SERVER :: nList %@", [products ProductName]);
            }
        }
    }
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(updateNewView:) withObject:shoppingListFromWebserver waitUntilDone:NO];
}

-(void) updateNewView:(NSMutableArray*) result
{
    _shoppingList = result;
    NSLog( @"new list - number of news :: %u", [_shoppingList count]);

    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1; // the number of different sections in your table view
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [_shoppingList count]; // the number of data in your shopping list
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ListCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    //cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    // Configure the cell...

    id shopList = [_shoppingList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.textLabel.text = [shopList ShoppingListName];
    NSNumber *sid = [shopList ShoppingListId];
    //[self loadItemsInList:sid];
    NSNumber *prodcount = [prodForList objectForKey:sid];
    NSString* pcTostring = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", prodcount];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = pcTostring;

    return cell;
```

The log actually tells me that I am getting some products for the last List it gets. Problem is that all `cell.detailText.text` fields are null, until the last reload, then all cells disappear.

I am pretty sure I'm doing it wrong, but I cant get my head around hot to get the products for the selected list, when I need to get the ShoppingListId from the `-(void) loadListsFromRemoteServer` call in order to do the `-(void) loadItemsInList:(NSNumber*)slistId`

WCF connection was made with the help of wsdl2obj

Comment: What do you get if you NSLog([shopList ShoppingListName]) in cellForRowAtIndexPath?

Comment: I get the names of the ShoppingLists.

Comment: I have edited my post. I forgot to add the `[self loadItemsInList:[slist ShoppingListId]];` in the `(void) operation:(NemListBindingOperation *)operation completedWithResponse:(NemListBindingResponse *)response`method

The app now terminates when looping through the products on the lists

Comment: `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[tns2_Product ShoppingListId]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8960790'`